# IOS Packaging in Sencha touch 2

Tags: c++, ios, json, extjs

When trying to package my sencha touch 2 test application, I receive the following error messages:

> **The application was successfully packaged [ERROR] Assertion failed: (type_ == stringValue), function asCString, file src/json_value.cpp,
>   line 679.**

It works absolutely fine on simulator.

My **Packager.json** file contains:

```
{
    "applicationName":"Myapp",
    "applicationId":"com.company.myapp",
    "bundleSeedId":"KPXFEPZ6EF",
    "iconName":"./icon.png",
    "versionString":"1.0",
    "outputPath":"build/",
    "inputPath":"../MyApp",
    "configuration":"Release",
    "platform":"iOS",
    "deviceType":"Universal",
    "certificatePath":"/Users/Me/Desktop/Certificates.p12",
    "orientations": [
        "portrait",
        "landscapeLeft",
        "landscapeRight",
        "portraitUpsideDown"
    ]
}
```

I think the certificate path is the one causing this error.

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I GUESS YOU NEED TO ADD "certificateAlias"

Comment: I had the same error, and after adding "certificateAlias" it compiled fine.